# Wireguard suddenly stopped working

Tags: wireguard

About a week ago I managed to run my own Wireguard based vpn server. Everything was fine until a few days ago when I noticed that clients stopped receiving data. Googling the issue didn't get problem solved. I tried analyzing traffic going from a client to the server via wireshark and learned that handshake doesn't complete (endless Handshake initiation packets originating from a client machine with no server response whatsoever). Here's the contents of wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 192.168.69.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 192.168.69.8/32
```

Here's a sample client configuration

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 192.168.69.8/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = VPS_IP:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

I double checked public/private key contents on both sides to avoid any inconsistencies. I had a suspicion that it's a firewall blocking all traffic, but didn't find anything in a kernel log that would confirm it

Comment: You can try to change the port 51820 to something else, in case somebody is filtering your traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it by regenerating server's public/private key pair!

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me. Thought I was going crazy double and triple checking everything when my clients were suddenly unable to connect after it was working fine for over a year.